# Document.BuiltInDocumentProperties makes the document dirty and prompts to save everytime

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word, vsto, word-automation

The [Document.BuiltInDocumentProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.builtindocumentproperties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) makes the document dirty and prompts to save everytime even nothing has changed.

I am trying to get the template of the document in the document change event

```
ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Template"]
```

But [ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.customdocumentproperties.aspx) works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Template template = (Template)ActiveDocument.get_AttachedTemplate();
```

This code also gets the template of the document and it doesn't makes the document dirty. But still curious to know why ***ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Template"]*** makes document dirty.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the logic in why this makes the document dirty, perhaps it is a bug. You can work around it thought just by doing the following.

> ActiveDocument.Saved = true;

Answer (score 0):

Safer:

```
dim isSaved as boolean

isSaved = activeDocument.Saved
myTemplate = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Template")
ActiveDocument.Saved = isSaved
```